# MySQL emulator in Java

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

How can I bind a Java application to the port a MySQL database is currently running on to emulate a MySQL database ?

I am developing a middleware between an authentication system and a MySQL database. All of the applications that have been developed so far directly connect to the MySQL database, and my aim is to develop a Java application that is going to emulate the database: receive incoming requests (queries), perform some actions (queuing, checks, and etc.), send the request to the MySQL db, receive the response, and send back the response to the caller.

I am unable to find details of the format of MySQL requests. After binding to a specific port, how can I parse the incoming MySQL requests ? It is also essential that connections are kept alive during the process, so the other applications don't think that there is a connection issue.

Comment: you may choose to first create a port 3306 proxy server with send thru to say mysql actually hanging out on another port. It would be an intermediary. And of course understanding the protocol slowly overtime.

Comment: I have found few proxy applications that provide bridges between the client applications and the mysql db, but none of them provide open APIs to manually perform operations. They all support a certain set of tools (load balancing, result filtering and etc.). I did go through some of the source files, but mysql is mostly written in C, and takes a while to grasp the details of the source codes. I am interested in finding an interceptor API to allow me parse/redirect the incoming requests.

Comment: I am saying he should write a small proxy server, @BigOnn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to implement the MySQL connection protocol on my own, and used [MySQL Internals - Connection Phase](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/connection-phase.html) as a reference. Looking at the existing open source implementations of connectors helped to understand the details as well. Essentially, I am implementing a very basic customized MySQL proxy server in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily bind your Java application to port 3306 (MySQL's default port number) as long as MySQL is not also using it on the same machine.

However, in order to understand the protocol used through that port, you may need to dig through the MySQL source code. MySQL have a '[Guided tour of the MySQL source code](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/guided-tour.html)' that is probably a good place to start.